# How can I insert coupon code in php form

Tags: php, forms, paypal, coupon

I have a php form on my website.
How to insert a coupon value in this form:

```
##<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" style="display: block; text-align: right;">';
echo '  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />';
echo '  <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1" />';
echo '  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="55CV8WBDMXBUA" />';
echo '  <input type="hidden" name="cn" value="Message optionnel sur votre commande" />';
echo '  <input type="hidden" name="cs" value="blablabla code truc" />';
echo $bt_paypal_objets;
echo '  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR" />';
echo '  <input type="hidden" name="shipping_1" value="' . AjoutZeroSomme($frais_port) . '" />';
echo '  <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.couleurs-arc-en-ciel.com/panier-retour.html" />';
echo '  <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.couleurs-arc-en-ciel.com/panier.html" />';
echo '  <input type="submit" value="Payer via PayPal" style="font-size: 20px;" />';
echo '</form>';

echo '<form action="panier-imprimer.html" method="get" target="_blank" style="display: block; text-align: right;">';
echo '    <input type="submit" value="Payer par chèque" style="font-size: 20px;" />';
echo '</form>'##
```

Answer (score 0):

> use this

```
<input type="hidden" name="discount_amount" value="your value">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ramesh, it works with "discount_amount_1 in my case

Comment: Glad it worked for you and thanks for telling the other option also :)